# Setup api key for freebase queries from appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, freebase, api-key

I have followed these instructions: https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys/. I registered the freebase service and added the Simple API key for browser apps to the query: https://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?key=keygoeshere&query={MQLquery}

I then get the following error:

```
 {u'code': 100, u'message': u'Invalid API Key (Key not found)', u'stat': u'fail'}
```

If I remove the key from the query it works locally but remotely I get: [freebase api error on deployment to appengine: DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800245/freebase-api-error-on-deployment-to-appengine-downloaderror-applicationerror). Which I believe is due to freebase blocking the appengine because the key is not registered or recognised

Comment: Will a browser key work when you hit it from a server?  To create a browser key you have to tell it what domain will be in the Referer, and you don't have a Referer.  I think you want a server key, but in that case you need to tell it the IP ranges requests will come from, which can be tricky for Google App Engine (but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149470/google-app-engine-list-of-ip-addresses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs say that the old `http://api.freebase.com` API [has been deprecated](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_API) (first paragraph).

You should access Freebase through google url: `https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?q=bob&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>`

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search takes free text as the query. I need to be more specific and search for a particular type with particular attributes. I cannot workout how to do this with https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808534/non-unique-query-with-freebase-mql-read-google-api

Comment: That's a completely different problem, but a) the question you linked to has been answered with an answer which will work for mqlread and b) the results from the search API can be constrained if that API is a better fit for your application.